# Can a concept satisfaction of an expression, contains both type and the reference?

Tags: c++, c++20

Is there a way to make the following code not so bloated?

I mean join both type and a reference somehow (`||` does not work).

```
template<typename T>
concept IntegralVector = std::integral<typename T::value_type> &&
requires(T t)
{
    { t.size() } -> std::convertible_to<std::size_t>;
}
&& (requires(T t)
{
    { t[0] } -> std::same_as<typename T::value_type&>;
} || requires(T t)
{
    { t[0] } -> std::same_as<typename T::value_type>;
});
```

A working trick can be:

```
{ 0 + t[0] } -> std::integral;
```

But I want to stick with `typename T::value_type`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably want something like this:

```cpp
template <typename T, typename U>
concept decays_to = std::same_as<std::decay_t<T>, U>;
```

To use as:

```cpp
template<typename T>
concept IntegralVector =
    std::integral<typename T::value_type>
    && requires (T t) {
        { t.size() } -> std::convertible_to<std::size_t>;
        { t[0] } -> decays_to<typename T::value_type>;
    };
```

This also catches `value_type const&` as an option, which I'm not sure was intentionally omitted.

Comment: Won't work if `T::value_type` is a reference though.

Comment: @Jarod42 Which it never should be.

Comment: Whereas `std::vector<T&>` is not possible, `MyVector<T&>` might ;-)

Comment: @Jarod42 Doesn't matter. `value_type` should still be `T` there.

Answer (score 6):

Another alternative is to use C++23 [`auto(x)`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2021/p0849r8.html), which is the *decay-copy* in the language:

```
#include<concepts>

template<typename T>
concept IntegralVector = std::integral<typename T::value_type> &&
requires(T t) {
  { t.size() } -> std::convertible_to<std::size_t>;
  { auto(t[0]) } -> std::same_as<typename T::value_type>;
};
```

[Demo.](https://godbolt.org/z/bYxzTeaj7)

Comment: This is the best answer but my g++11 does not support auto(x) yet. If I remember it, I give you the answer when g++12 become available.